# Search for unique record for columns with multiple identifer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This maybe a little confusing, I'm trying to get a result where it'll only return records without the "F" as tran_type. The problem is some record contains both the "C" and "F" tran_type so if I do a (where tran_type <> "F") it shows all the records (1,2,3,4,5) but I only want record_no 2 and 4 to show. Any assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
record_no   name    description tran_type   trancode     amount 
1           user1   apple          C        1149         $76.27 
1           user1   apple          C        1149         $25.00 
1           user1   apple          F        1164         $(2,500.00)
1           user1   apple          C        1161         $(199.76)
2           user2   orange         C        1157         $150.00 
2           user2   orange         C        1158         $(150.00)
3           user3   orange         C        1159         $(25.00)
3           user3   orange         F        1164         $(1,305.62)
3           user3   orange         C        1151         $16.90 
3           user3   orange         C        1164         $(994.38)
4           user4   orange         C        1159         $10.70 
4           user4   orange         C        1147         $35.00 
5           user5   apple          C        1149         $5.50 
5           user5   apple          F        1164         $(50.00)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
Select * 
From table1
Where record_no 
Not in (select record_no from table1 where tran_type = 'F')
```

Assuning that table1 is the table name

Comment: Would this be in reverse if I want to search for record with only "F" as tran_type?

Comment: Just replace `where tran_type = 'F')` with `where tran_type <> 'F')`

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate the prompt replies.